# Django Rest Framework format decimal field to 2 decimal places (for output)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use Django and DRF,I have many decimal fields in models, like

```
amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=4)
```

I want format output Two decimal places ，in every serializers field can do this

```
amount = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=2)
```

There's an easyer way?

Comment: that's the only way of doing it :)

Comment: You mean easier than changing a kwarg?

Comment: @MarcusLind Maybe my idea is bad, I wanted to use process_response method  in middleware so only modify one place

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In DRF there is a way to override only options but not the entire field:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('amount',)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'amount': {'max_digits': 16, 'decimal_places': 2}
        }
```

Or if you have many same decimal fields you should use your own custom DecimalField with predefined common options.

Answer (score 0):

**Both will work for 2 decimal point value:**

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    id = serializers.IntegerField() 
    name = serializers.CharField()   
    decimal_value = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)   

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'decimal_value']
```

**And:**

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.Serializer): 
        id = serializers.IntegerField() 
        name = serializers.CharField()   
        decimal_value = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

**For more info, please visit:** https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#decimalfield